# Dynamically add MenuItems to PrimeNG Menu after Angular GET request

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have an array of Show objects which hold just an ID and name. I was using these to set up a sidebar with Bootstrap but am now trying to use PrimeNG.

I know that PrimeNG Menus work with MenuItem objects and I am trying to keep my original Shows[] and set up a separate MenuItem[] to feed the Menu component.

```
export class ShowSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  shows?: Array<Show>;
  items!: MenuItem[];
  item?: MenuItem;

  getShows(): void {
    this.showService.getShowTitles().subscribe(res => this.shows = res);
  }

  constructor(
    private showService: ShowService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getShows();

    this.shows?.forEach(show => {
      this.item = {label: show.title};
      this.items.push(this.item);
    })
  }
}
```

getShows() is where the Shows[] is filled. After I call that I add MenuItems to the MenuItem[], but nothing shows in the menu when it runs.

```
<p-menu [model]="items"></p-menu>
```

The template is just this.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: `this.item = {label: show.title};` replace it with `const item: MenuItem = {label: show.title};` and then push it to `this.items`. I am assuming you have imported all the modules correctly inside your module file.

Comment: It still doesn't show any menu items. I can get the menu to show up but it doesn't populate with any of my data.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that by using BehaviorSubect to inform Angular that something has changed in the component:

```
items: BehaviorSubject<MenuItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject<MenuItem[]>([]);
menus: MenuItem[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.items.subscribe({
    next: (data: MenuItem[]) => this.menus = data
  });
}

setMenu() {
    this.apiService.get('/auth/getMenus').subscribe({
      next: (menus: Array<ApplicationMenuModel>) => {
        var m: MenuItem[] = [];

        menus.forEach(c => {

          const item: MenuItem = {
            label: c.label,
            icon: c.icon,
            routerLink: [c.link]
          };

          m.push(item);
        });

        this.items.next(m);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

in the markup, I am biding the menu bar to the menus object:
`<p-menubar [model]="menus"></p-menubar>`

Hope that helps.